# @@redux-form/UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS is unintentionally clearing my _error state

Tags: redux-form

I'm setting up form-wide errors pretty much exactly like the [Submit Validation Example](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/submitValidation/) from the docs.

But unlike the example, my `_error` object is removed as soon as I do any change in any other form field on my page. On the example page the `_error` is always shown until the button is pressed again.

Using the Redux dev tools extension in Chrome I see that the action `@@redux-form/UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS` is dispatched on the first change I do on any other form field after `_error` has been set and this action is clearing my `_error` object in the form state.

- How can I control when this action is dispatched?
- Can I make it not clear my `_error` object?

Answer (score 0):

Your form-wide (`_error`) error is from a failed form submission? i.e. something other than sync validation?

The code as it is now will definitely clear that error. The reason being that once the user has modified something in the form, it seems reasonable to remove the complaint about their past behavior.

However, this seems like a reasonable thing that someone might want to configure. Please submit a feature request referencing this question.